# What is attribute md-nav-sref of md-nav-item is used for?

Tags: angular-material

In below simple navigator bar example, there is a attribute called `md-nav-sref="some"`. Without that attribute, Angular doesn't display the navigator bar buttons. What is `md-nav-sref` used for? Is there anyway I can used `md-nav-sref` to change the content of `#show-this` `div` element?

```
<md-nav-bar md-selected-nav-item="projectContentType">
  <md-nav-item md-nav-sref="some" name="module-view">module view</md-nav-item>
</md-nav-bar>
<div id="show-this"> {{projectContentType}} </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Offical Docs](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdNavItem) says that `md-nav-sref` is used as `Ui-router state to transition to when this link is clicked. Renders as a ui-sref`. So `some` is the `ui-route` state name.